# Cannot remove parent item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to remove the parent item of an  `<a>`, this is the html:

```
<div>123321<a class="del" rel="32" href="#">X</a></div>
```

And this is the code:

```
$(function()
{
    $('.del').click(function(e)
    {
        $(e).parent().remove();
    });
});
```

But nothing happen, why? [JSFIDDLE.](http://jsfiddle.net/8w8v9/1814/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(You could use `this` as mentioned in the other answer but also you have possibility to use `e.target` that refer to the current object also). so instead of passing event `e` you could pass the object of the current clicked  element using `e.target`, check the example below.

```js
$(function() {
    $('.del').on('click', function(e) {
        $(e.target).parent().remove();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<div>123321<a class="del" rel="32" href="#">X</a></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're passing the `event` object to jQuery, not the current element. Use `this` in place of `e` inside your handler:

```
$(function() {
    $('.del').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
});
```

In the above example, notice how `e` is used to represent the event that occurred, while `this` is used to represent the event's *target element*.

```js
$(function() {
    $('.del').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<div>123321<a class="del" rel="32" href="#">X</a></div>
```